# Datanode is not connected to the Namenode cloudera

Tags: hadoop, configuration, cloudera, talend

I want to acces cloudera from a distant machine via Talend for big data. In order to do that i changed the ip of the host in cloudera by editing the file /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network.
I can acces cloudera from Talend. However the problem is that my datanode and Namenode seems to be not connected. When i check the log details of my Datanode i get the following errors :

```
Block pool BP-1183376682-127.0.0.1-1433878467265 (Datanode Uuid null) service to quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8022 beginning handshake with NN
```

`Initialization failed for Block pool BP-1183376682-127.0.0.1-1433878467265 (Datanode Uuid null) service to quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8022 Datanode denied communication with namenode because the host is not in the include-list: DatanodeRegistration(127.0.0.1, datanodeUuid=5802ab81-2c28-4beb-b155-cac31567d23a, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-83500942-6c65-4ecd-a0c2-a448be86bcb0;nsid=975591446;c=0)`

the datanode still uses the wrong ip adress ( 127.0.0.1 ) even though i made the modifications in core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml by editing the previous ip adress by the new one.

I followed the steps given in this tutorial to do so :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSGpYHjGIRY

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 8, the `/etc/hosts` will contain entry for 127.0.1.1 with your hostname you gave during Linux installation. Cloudera will use this IP-address for some of its services.

A regular HDFS will contain multiple servers with different hostnames/IP-addresses and will list those IPs as allowed. As your log says, the traffic is originating from 127.0.0.1, which is not the IP-address of your hostname.

For Cloudera single-server setup, the only way I found was to do the initial setup so, that `/etc/hosts` doesn't have the 127.0.1.1 entry in it.